# unchecking multiple checkboxes AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, checkbox

I have a placeholder movieclip on stage named cbHolder and some code that creates a series of checkboxes, 33 in all, assigns an 'ON CHANGE' event listener to each of them and then adds them into the cbHolder MC. The event listener fires the function iChanged which looks like this:

```
var cbSearchArray:Array = new Array();
function iChanged(event:Event):void{
if (event.target.selected == true){
        trace(event.target.name + " is checked");
        cbSearchArray.push(event.target.name);
        trace("array is:" + cbSearchArray);
        }
        else{
            trace(event.target.name + " is unchecked");
            cbSearchArray.splice(cbSearchArray.indexOf(event.target.name), 1);
            trace("array is:" + cbSearchArray);
            }
    }
```

This all works great, adds and removes array elements like a thing possessed and I'm really pleased. I didn't know I had it in me... but what I'm really stuck on right now is an efficient way of unchecking all checkboxes, or checking all beckboxes via a button. When I try and iterate through the array with a for loop and try setting the checkbox with

```
cbSearchArray[i].selected = false;
```

I get the error: Cannot create property selected on String. I don't understand why Flash is not seeing them as object names..!! If I try

```
cbHolder.cbSearchArray[i].selected = false;
```

I get the error: A term is undefined and has no properties.

I'm totally, totally lost and after goggling for a whole day I've come across nothing that will help. In the hope that someone can point me in the right direction I'm posting it here and asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having an array with object names, you can have an array with object references. Each time you create a checkbox, add it to your checkbox array, otherwise it's going to try to modify the .selected property on a string which would reasonably throw the error you're getting.

Here's somewhat what you can do:

```
var cbArray:Array = new Array();

function createCheck():void{
    var cb:CheckBox = new CheckBox();
    cbArray.push(cb);
}
```

and then you can refer to cbArray[i].selected when you're iterating through it.

Another way you can it if you like is use the getChildByName method to get your checkbox.

```
var cb:CheckBox = cbHolder.getChildByName(cbSearchArray[i]) as CheckBox;
cb.selected = false;
```

However I strongly recommend against this approach as using naming could open you up to a number of potential problems. I recommend that you just use references.

Comment: Did try something close to your first proposal. However, by using push(cb); The array is simply filled with [object CheckBox] so using .push(cb.name) I get the correct values. However. I still get the  error  Cannot create property selected on String.

Comment: Do you really need an array full of their names? [object CheckBox] is a reference to a CheckBox object and you can access any of its properties through the array. cbArray[i].name, cbArray[i].selected, etc.

Comment: You sir, are a champion and I cannot thank you enough. I never knew that the array held all the information needed without the use of .name. I do however need the names as these will be stored in a database against an item of inventory. This is my next quest... getting an array or values into SQL... wish me luck as I think I'm gonna need it.. Many many thanks again MasterRoro

Comment: It was my pleasure! Best of luck.